# Como consultar os valores não utilizados numa sequence NUMBER(3)

Tags: sql, pl-sql, oracle11g

Fiz esse programa que retorna os códigos da PK utilizados.

```
DECLARE
  -- LOCAL VARIABLES HERE
  L_RESULT VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN

  FOR I IN (Select cd_local_atendimento 
                 from tb_local_atendimento_sa
                 order by 1) loop
  
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COD:'||I.CD_LOCAL_ATENDIMENTO);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Criei um cursor para verificar os códigos usados, mas existem códigos não usados.

Comment: Sequence garante unicidade não integridade , para integridade exitem outras soluções que não vou discutir aqui , para achar as "banguelas" ... select rownum x from dual connect by level where level <= <maior cd_local> minus select cd_local_atendimento from tb_local_atendimento_sa creio ser isto , citando de memória.

Comment: select level from dual connect by level <= <maior cd_local_atendimento>
minus select cd_local_atendimento from tb_local_atendimento_sa

Comment: deu certo, valeu!